# how to retrieve specific Queues using package.xml

Tags: deployment, package, queue, package.xml

I have some Queues which needs to move to other sandbox. Please suggest the `package.xml` structure

Answer (score 2):

Simply include [Queue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_queue.htm) type in your `package.xml`. Then retrieve it from your sendbox and migrate to another

```
<types>
    <members>NameOfDesiredQueue</members>
    <name>Queue</name>
</types>
```

after retrieval new file `NameOfDesiredQueue.queue` will be created in `src/queues` folder. If you want to add members, add new elements to this file. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Queue xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <doesSendEmailToMembers>false</doesSendEmailToMembers>
    <name>queue1</name>
    <queueMembers>
        <groups>
            <publicGroup>All Internal Users</publicGroup>
        </groups>
        <roleAndSubordinates>
            <roleAndSubordinate>role1</roleAndSubordinate>
        </roleAndSubordinates>
        <roleAndSubordinatesInternal>
            <roleAndSubordinateInternal>role2</roleAndSubordinateInternal>
        </roleAndSubordinatesInternal>
        <roles>
            <role>role3</role>
        </roles>
        <users>
            <user>admin@myorg.com</user>
            <user>user1@myorg.com</user>
            <user>user2@myorg.com</user>
        </users>
    </queueMembers>
    <queueRoutingConfig>my_omni_routing_config</queueRoutingConfig>
    <queueSobject>
        <sobjectType>Case</sobjectType>
    </queueSobject>
    <queueSobject>
        <sobjectType>Lead</sobjectType>
    </queueSobject>
</Queue>
```

Comment: using above .Only queue details are coming.If any user/roles/public Groups are assigned which is not coming in retrieval package

Comment: @tarun I have updated my answer with membners of queue

Comment: Thanks for answer.but when i retrieving the Queue ,The other details like Queue Members needs to be retrieve in the same file .

Comment: @tarun They aren't automatically retrieved in a basic package.xml. You will need to explicitly list them in your package.xml file for migration.